# A question about "seems like (as If, as though)"

Tags: grammar

1. He seems ***to be*** happy.
2. ***It*** seems ***that*** he is happy. (formal style)
3. ***It*** seems ***like*** (***as if***, ***as though***) he is happy. (informal style)

1) Sentence #1 ; I assume that 'to infinitive' functions as ***subjective*** ***complement*** (that is, impersonal subject + intransitive verb + subjective complement).

2) Sentence #2, 3 ; I assume that

(1) '***it***' functions as ***extraposed it*** to set up 'end focus',

(2) the conjunctions - '***that***' and '***like***', '***as*** ***if*** , ***as*** ***though***' in informal style - lead not a subjective complement but a ***real subject*** clause (that is, subject + intransitive verb + real subject clause).

(3) in above Sentence #2, 3 '***seems***' is justified to function as an intransitive verb, which doesn't need a subjective complement but leads a real subject clause?

I sum up my assumptions in question, wchich are right?;

1.the '***seems***' in the sentence #1 and #2, 3 are functioning different;

• sentence #1; '***seems***' is an intransitive verb, which leads '***to*** ***be***' - as a subjective complement.

• sentence #2, 3; '***seems***' is an intransitive verb, which leads conjunctions - '***that***, ***like***, ***as if***, ***as though***' - as a ***true subject clause*** (not a subjective complement clause) triggered by ***extraposed it***.

2.Thus, the syntax isn't the same between the sentence #1, which begins with the personal pronoun - '***he***', and the sentence #2, 3, which begins with the impersonal pronoun - '***it***'.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the distinction you make between a "complete" and an "incomplete" intransitive verb. _Seem_ (as well as _appear_, which has almost identical syntax) is an intransitive (1-place) verb that takes a subject complement. But English does not like subject complements with short verbs, e.g: *_For him to be happy seems_. So something has to change the structure, and either A-Raising in (1) or Extraposition in (2-3) will do the job of putting something else small in the subject slot and a main verb right after that.

Comment: Thanks, John Lawler. Do you you agree to analyze above "that, like (as if)" clauses in (2), (3) as a real subject?

Comment: The clauses are the subjects; they function as noun phrases. _That, like, as if_ in this case are complementizers, not noun phrases. So they can't be subjects; subjects have to be noun phrases. Complementizers introduce the clause; they don't have grammatical relations in it.

Comment: I'm confused since you wrote, "The clauses are the subjects; they function as noun phrases. That, like, as if in this case are complementizers, not noun phrases." You mean that above "that, like, as if" clauses in (2), (3) isn't a real subject despite extraposed it?

Comment: What is your actual question? You give a long series of analyses but don't follow them up with a question. If it's simply *Am I right?* that's too broad, given how much you've said.

Comment: The complementizers are words that introduce clauses. These clauses are all subject noun clauses. I wanted to emphasize that the complementizers are not the subjects -- the subjects are clauses, and the complementizers merely introduce and mark them.

Comment: Jason Bassford, in short, how do you analyze above "that, like, as if clauses" in (2), (3)? Are they all a real subject clause?

Comment: John Lawler, thanks much for your additional clarification.